# Can't get the inherited class functions in JS

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I build some base PopupBuilder class and want to implement it in some different usecases. For each case I create a class extends the base class.
So:

```
function PopupBuilder () {
    var _this = this;

    this.buildPopup = function () {
        var popup = $('<div>', {
        id: "popup",
        class: "full-page",
        click: clickHandler});
    } //works fine

    function acceptChanges () {}
    function clickHandler (event) { // works fine 
        console.log(_this); // _this doesn't overrides by child class _this. Should it? 
        acceptChanges(event); // doesn't overrides by child class function as well
    }
}

function ToServerSender (text) {
    var _this = this;
    function acceptChanges (event) {
        // send data to server
    }
}

ToServerSender.prototype = new PopupBuilder();

var updateFile = new ToServerSender();
updateFile.buildPopup();
```

I create an instance of child class, why I can't get to child class code and override/extend the base class?
How should I rewrite the code it will works?

Comment: Can you show us how `clickHandler` is used?

Comment: Those are local variables (functions), they can't be overridden at all. You'd only overwrite properties (methods). However, [you'll need to fix your inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12592913/1048572) before you can do that.

Comment: I've edited the post, added buildPopup function code.
I've changed all the functions to _this.funcName and even added `ToServerSender.prototype.constructor = ToServerSender;` from that post. It didn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bear in mind that the way OOP works in JavaScript is vastly different from class-style OOP.

So let's break it down a bit:

```
var _this = this;
```

This assignment takes place when the `new PopupBuilder()` constructor is called toward the end of the code you posted there. The `this` here refers to an object of type `PopupBuilder`, and through inheritance is essentially "shared" among all instances of `ToServerSender`. Each `ToServerSender` does not get its own copy of this `_this`.

```
function acceptChanges () {}
```

This is just a function that exists inside your `PopupBuilder` constructor. It's not a method. It can't be overridden by defining a new one in the `ToServerSender` constructor:

```
console.log(_this); // _this doesn't overrides by child class _this. Should it?
```

As explained above, the `_this` here is referring to the one instance of `_this` that was created the one time you called the `PopupBuilder` constructor and it is shared among all instances of `ToServerSender`.

```
acceptChanges(event); // doesn't overrides by child class function as well
```

This is simply a closure to the `acceptChanges` function inside the `PopupBuilder` constructor. It can't be overridden.

---

**So what can you do?**

**1. Use overridable methods.**

One thing you need to do is assign methods to `this` so that child objects can override them:

```
function PopupBuilder () {
    var _this = this;

    this.buildPopup = function () {} //works fine

    this.acceptChanges = function () {}

    this.clickHandler = function (event) { 
        console.log(this); 
        this.acceptChanges(event); 
    }
}
```

Here, we have the constructor assigning functions to properties of `this` so that they can be inherited via the prototype chain and overridden as needed:

```
function ToServerSender (text) {
    var _this = this;

    // overrides prototype's  .acceptchanges
    this.acceptChanges = function (event) {
        // send data to server
    }
}
```

**2. Create the child type's prototype using `Object.create()`, not a constructor.**

Using a constructor to create a prototype on a child type is a bit outdated. The [new way to do this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2184-object-create-improves-constructor-based-inheritance-in-javascript-it-doesn-t-replace-it.htm) is to use `Object.create`, to create a copy of the parent object's prototype:

```
ToServerSender.prototype = Object.create(PopupBuilder.prototype);
```

But this leaves the `ToServerSender` prototype without all the stuff that was initialized in the `PopupBuilder` constructor. This is actually a good thing, because the `PopupBuilder` constructor was creating one copy of its private variables that were going to be shared between all of the `ToServerSenders` in existence, potentially wreaking havok.

The solution to this is to...

**3. Call the parent constructor from the child constructor:**

```
function ToServerSender(text) {
    PopupBuilder.call(this);

    var _this = this;
    this.a = "hello";
    //this class overrides acceptChanges from PopupBuilder
    this.acceptChanges = function(event) {
        // send data to server
        console.log(1);
        console.log(_this);
    }
}
```

What happens here is that `ToServerSender` calls the `PopupBuilder` constructor on *itself*, so that when `_this` is created inside that constructor, it is referring to the `ToServerSender`, and not some shared `PopupBuilder`. This allows you to use it in closures and clear up some of the problems you were experiencing.

So those are the main things to keep in mind. I know this is a ton of stuff, but the more you use it, the easier it will become.

Comment: The last solution worked as magic. Magic because I didn't understand completely why this is so different from the first one.
And the first solution didn't work at all. I still think it should work, maybe in slightly another syntax but sould work. 
Is there a way to make it working?

Comment: @Doc999tor I'm not sure what you mean by "first solution" and "last solution". What I was suggesting was that you should do all three of those 3 things that I listed, not just one (if that's what you mean).

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the functions to the object.

```
function PopupBuilder () {
    var _this = this;

    this.buildPopup = function () {} //works fine

    this.acceptChanges = function() { console.log(2);}
    this.clickHandler = function(event) { // works fine 
        console.log(_this); // _this doesn't overrides by child class _this. Should it? 
        //Look a the difference here: when you use _this.acceptChanges it prints 2 when you use this.acceptChanges() it prints 1 to the console.
        this.acceptChanges(event); // doesn't overrides by child class function as well

    }
}

function ToServerSender (text) {
    var _this = this;
    this.a = "hello";
    //this class overrides acceptChanges from PopupBuilder
    this.acceptChanges = function(event) {
        // send data to server
        console.log(1);
        console.log(_this);
    }
}

ToServerSender.prototype = new PopupBuilder();

var updateFile = new ToServerSender();
updateFile.buildPopup();
```

Look at the above code to see how it works.

When in `PopupBuilder` console.log prints `_this` it uses a reference to `this` in that scope (which contained the old `acceptChanges`. However in `ToServerSender` the scope has changed. This instance has other properties and is referred to by the `this` object in that scope. This example show the difference between using a reference to this and the object this.

On a side note: when using more than 1 instance of an object use function references to avoid memory issues.

example

```
    this.clickHandler = clickHandlerPopupBuilder
    function clickHandlerPopupBuilder(event) {
        console.log(_this);
        this.acceptChanges(event);          
    }
```

Comment: Changing the function expression to a function declaration doesn't in and of itself save any memory. It's moving the function outside of the constructor that might save some memory. But if it's outside the constructor, it can't have a closure on `_this`.

Comment: @JLRishe you're correct. You lose the `_this`. Can be solved with binding. Thanks for adding.